# Unable to automate AS400 Mainframe in C#

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange

We connect AS400 Mainframe by using HQD400.hod which is an emulator, we want to scrape the HQD400 screen we are using clsEhllapi.dll which is used for scrapping the AS400 MF emulator screen.

We are using the following code

```
Process p = new Process();
string url = @"C:\Softwares\IBM i Access Client Solutions\IBM i Access Client Solutions\IBM\JACCESS\IBM\iAccessClient\Emulator\HQD400.hod";
Process.Start(url);

UInt32 screen = EhllapiWrapper.Connect("A");

public static UInt32 Connect(string sessionID) 
{ 
     StringBuilder Data = new StringBuilder(4);
     Data.Append(sessionID);
     UInt32 rc=0;
     UInt32 f=HA_CONNECT_PS;
     UInt32 l=4;
     return  EhllapiFunc.hllapi(out f, Data, out l, out rc);
}
```

But we are unable to connect to the HQD400 MF emulator. Please let me know if any details required.

Comment: FYI only: The AS/400 was never classified a MainFrame computer; thus the tag *ibm-midrange* identifying that system as MidRange; there are very few AS/400 still operational. The IBM midrange are IBM Power servers running combinations of: • IBM i • AIX • Linux  The IBM i on IBM Power is what most businesses would be running, else they are running on very outdated hardware and likely also outdated OS software.

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice example at [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9615/Using-EHLLAPI-in-C). Hope it helps.

The emulator interprets the 5250 data stream ([Google Link](http://www.google.com/search?q=5250%20data%20stream%20programming))

**Side Note:**

I wouldn't touch screen scraping with a 10 foot pole, Careful it might give you eye cancer.

Depending on your end goal consider:

- Rational Open Acess For RPG (Free)

  - [RPG Open Access: You Don't Know What You Don't Know](http://www.itjungle.com/tfh/tfh020612-story03.html)
  - [Charges Dropped, Rational Open Access Goes Free](http://www.itjungle.com/tfh/tfh020612-story02.html)
- Buy a screen scapper form a ISV, like looksoftware or Profound Logic. (Quick and Costly)
- Re-write the front-end with calls to back-end RPGLE programs which contains the business logic. (Potentially slow,complex and expensive)